# Finding a general formula for the function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

I need some help! During a moment of research, I wanted to find a general formula with a function $f$.
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
0&& \text{if $x\in\mathbb R^*$}\\
1&&\text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$
The domain of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb R$.

Try to determine an explicit formula for this function. And if we can't, does an explicit formula really exist?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly is the question? You already have an explicit formula. The function $f$ is zero for all x different from zero und $f(0)$ is equal to zero. What else could you wish for? :)

Comment: I suppose that OP wants a formula without case distinctions, something akin to $f(x) = \sin^2(x) - 3\cos(x)$. However, note that pretty much all _simple_ real functions that can be written in such a way are continuous while OP's function is not. As compositions of continuous functions are continuous themselves, we can rule out the existence of such an expression representing $f$.

Comment: One sometimes denotes the function that is identically $1$ on some set $A$ and $0$ elsewhere---namely, the **characteristic function** of $A$--by $\chi_A$.

Comment: This is Kronecker Delta function. It is used in a lot of discrete signal-processing and has some analogous properties to Dirac-Delta function used in continuous signal-processing. I use "function" in a non-rigorous way. But searching for this might help you research further.

Comment: Of course, the answer depends on what functions you allow to appear in the combination used to represent $ f $. But take $ f ( x ) = 1 - | \mathrm { sgn } \: x | $ as an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, heck:

$$f(x) = 1 - \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{|x|+1|}\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor \frac{-x}{|x|+1}\right\rfloor\right)^2.$$

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea. Wouldn't this function also work?

$f(x) = 1 - \left\lceil \frac{x}{|x|+1} \right\rceil$

Comment: @Mrcrg  I don't think it works for negative $x$.  Try $x = -2.$

Comment: @Mrcrg  Maybe change the $x$ in the numerator to $|x|.$?

Comment: You're right, my mistake.

Comment: Indeed, just need to add with $x$ an absolute value. Damn, i love the ceil and floor function. Thanks for the help!